# Can mongodb report failover status?

Tags: mongodb, hook, replication, failover

I have 3-node Replica Set in MongoDB. Is there any possibility to configure it to automatically run a shell script when failover happens or one of nodes goes down?

I believe this is not a role of database but maybe there are some mongo plugins/tools made for that purpose like Sentinel for Redis or MHA Manager for MySQL which report what node failed and what node become new master and so on.